# How to apply a logical operator to all elements in a python list

Tags: python

I have a list of booleans in python. I want to AND (or OR or NOT) them and get the result. The following code works but is not very pythonic.

```
def apply_and(alist):
 if len(alist) > 1:
     return alist[0] and apply_and(alist[1:])
 else:
     return alist[0]
```

Any suggestions on how to make it more pythonic appreciated.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Logical `and` across all elements in `a_list`:

```
all(a_list)
```

Logical `or` across all elements in `a_list`:

```
any(a_list)
```

---

If you feel creative, you can also do:

```
import operator
def my_all(a_list):
  return reduce(operator.and_, a_list, True)

def my_any(a_list):
  return reduce(operator.or_, a_list, False)
```

keep in mind that those aren't evaluated in short circuit, whilst the built-ins are ;-)

another funny way:

```
def my_all_v2(a_list):
  return len(filter(None,a_list)) == len(a_list)

def my_any_v2(a_list):
  return len(filter(None,a_list)) > 0
```

and yet another:

```
def my_all_v3(a_list):
  for i in a_list:
    if not i:
      return False
  return True

def my_any_v3(a_list):
  for i in a_list:
    if i:
      return True
  return False
```

and we could go on all day, but yes, the pythonic way is to use `all` and `any` :-)

By the way, Python has not tail recursion elimination, so don't try to translate LISP code directly ;-)

Comment: operator.and_ is the bitwise and operator &, not the logical and.

Comment: luckly True and False (as the op wanted) are casted to 1 and 0 respectively, so the bitwise operators work as the logical ^_^

Comment: Worth noting... 2.5+ but very easy to backport.

Comment: Explained a lot of redundant versions, but didn't provide the syntax for the actual correct answer.

Comment: @jwg downvotes should be used for *wrong* answers, but anyway, feel free to improve it

Comment: I disagree that downvotes should only be used for wrong answers.

Comment: disagree whatever you want, it's in the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @AntsAasma But, as someone who was looking to use the ```|``` operator with some pandas dataframes, I liked this solution :)

Comment: Note that none of these answers are equivalent to `x1 or x2 or ...` or `x1 and x2 and ...`, if the variables are not boolean. E.g. `(4 or None or 3 is 4)` while `any([4, None, 3]) is True`.

Comment: Note that `reduce()` is in `functools` since Python 3.0

Comment: Thank you. `def _is_outside(x): return any([True for i in range(len(x)) if x[i] < 0 or x[i]>self.limits[i]] )` to quickly check if point x is within bonds.

Answer (score 34):

ANDing and ORing is easy:

```
>>> some_list = [True] * 100
# OR
>>> any(some_list)
True
#AND
>>> all(some_list)
True
>>> some_list[0] = False
>>> any(some_list)
True
>>> all(some_list)
False
```

NOTing is also fairly easy:

```
>>> [not x for x in some_list]
[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Of course, how you would use those results might require some interesting applications of DeMorgan's theorem.

Comment: If you want short-circuting of the not variant, simply use generator expressions: `all(not x for x in some_list)` (but that is the same as `not any(some_list)` (quite a natural expression, huh?)).

Answer (score 19):

[Reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) can do this:

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a and b, alist, True)
```

As fortran mentioned, all is the most succinct way to do it. But reduce answers the more general question "How to apply a logical operator to all elements in a python list?"

Comment: reduce isn't going away, AFAIK. it's being moved into the functools module, from its previous position in the global namespace

Comment: @eliben: Why talk about Python 3 in future tense? *reduce is still there*. `reduce` is `functools.reduce` *in Python 3*

Comment: If you remove the `, True`, this answer will be the only one actually equivalent to the question's code, for non-boolean lists.

Answer (score 13):

The idiom for such operations is to use the `reduce` function (global in Python 2.X, in module `functools` in Python 3.X) with an appropriate binary operator either taken from the `operator` module or coded explicitly. In your case, it's `operator.and_`

```
reduce(operator.and_, [True, True, False])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution:

```
def my_and(a_list):
    return not (False in a_list)

def my_or(a_list):
    return True in a_list
```

ANDing all elements will return True if all elements are True, hence no False in a list.
ORing is similar, but it should return True if at least one True value is present in a list.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers show, there are multiple ways to accomplish this task. Here's another solution that uses functions from the standard library:

```
from functools import partial

apply_and = all
apply_or = any
apply_not = partial(map, lambda x: not x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ls = [True, True, False, True, False, True]
    print "Original: ", ls
    print "and: ", apply_and(ls)
    print "or: ", apply_or(ls)
    print "not: ", apply_not(ls)
```