# Remove multiple string elements from a list which contains certain keywords

Tags: python

I have a list called files consists of string elements:

```
files = ['Upside Your Head.txt', 'The Mighty Quinn - [Remastered].txt', 'The Mighty Quinn - (live).txt', 'Fixin To Die (Mono version).txt', '10,000 Men - [Remastered].txt', '10,000 Men.txt', '10.000 Men - (live).txt']
```

I am trying to remove elements that contain specific keywords (e.g. Live, Remastered, Mono). The code I wrote was like this:

```
files = [i for i in files if '(Live)' not in i]
files = [i for i in files if '[Remastered]' not in i]
files = [i for i in files if '(Mono' not in i]
```

What is a better practice to include all the above three lines in one statement? Considering that I want to add more keywords later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step to generalize this is to combine multiple conditions with logical operators:

> ```
> files = [i for i in files if '(Live)' not in i]
> files = [i for i in files if '[Remastered]' not in i]
> files = [i for i in files if '(Mono' not in i]
> ```

becomes

```
files = [
    i for i in files
    if (
        '(Live)' not in i
        and '[Remastered]' not in i
        and '(Mono' not in i
    )
]
```

or, by means of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),

```
files = [
    i for i in files
    if not (
        '(Live)' in i
        or '[Remastered]' in i
        or '(Mono' in i
    )
]
```

Now, in order to be able to take the keywords from a predefined list and automatically adjust the number of conditions accordingly, we can use the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) functions:

- `a and b and c` can be replaced by `all([a, b, c])`
- `a or b or c` can be replaced by `any([a, b, c])`

(See: [How to apply a logical operator to all elements in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790520/how-to-apply-a-logical-operator-to-all-elements-in-a-python-list))

Instead of a list, we can also pass a *generator expression* to `all` and `any`.

Therefore, the condition

```
if (
    '(Live)' not in i
    and '[Remastered]' not in i
    and '(Mono' not in i
)
```

can be written as

```
if all(keyword not in i for keyword in ['(Live)', '[Remastered]', '(Mono'])
```

and

```
if not (
    '(Live)' in i
    or '[Remastered]' in i
    or '(Mono' in i
)
```

as

```
if not any(keyword in i for keyword in ['(Live)', '[Remastered]', '(Mono'])
```

As a result, the code can become

```
keywords = ['(Live)', '[Remastered]', '(Mono']
files = [i for i in files if all(keyword not in i for keyword in keywords)]
```

or

```
keywords = ['(Live)', '[Remastered]', '(Mono']
files = [i for i in files if not any(keyword in i for keyword in keywords)]
```

Comment: Wow! You took it a few steps further than the comment! Love it. Amazing step-by-step explanation

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It worked with me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this with a list comprehension for readibility -

```
files = ['Upside Your Head.txt', 
         'The Mighty Quinn - [Remastered].txt', 
         'The Mighty Quinn - (live).txt', 
         'Fixin To Die (Mono version).txt', 
         '10,000 Men - [Remastered].txt', 
         '10,000 Men.txt', 
         '10.000 Men - (live).txt']

rem = ['(live)','[Remastered]','(Mono']

[f for f in files if all(r not in f for r in rem)]
```

```
['Upside Your Head.txt', '10,000 Men.txt']
```

This is the same as this -

```
[f for f in files if not any(r in f for r in rem)]
```

```
['Upside Your Head.txt', '10,000 Men.txt']
```

Comment: I would change to more meaningful names than `i` and `j` and remove the brackets from the `all` argument to avoid unnecessary list creation. Except for that, that's the right solution IMO

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
files = ['Upside Your Head.txt', 'The Mighty Quinn - [Remastered].txt', 'The Mighty Quinn - (live).txt', 'Fixin To Die (Mono version).txt', '10,000 Men - [Remastered].txt', '10,000 Men.txt', '10.000 Men - (live).txt']
words = {'Remastered','Live'}

def need_to_collect(entry):
    for word in words:
        if word in entry:
            return False
    return True
    
clean_list = [x for x in files if need_to_collect(x)]
print(clean_list)
```

output

```
['Upside Your Head.txt', 'The Mighty Quinn - (live).txt', 'Fixin To Die (Mono version).txt', '10,000 Men.txt', '10.000 Men - (live).txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the keywords in a list and then iterate the list to adjust your 'files'

```
keywords = ['(Live)','[Remastered]','(Mono']

for keyword in keywords:
  files = [i for i in files if keyword not in i]
print(files)
```